# How to call sendKeyDownUpSync in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to programmatically switch a music track, but this code does not work in the background, how to solve this problem?

```java
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an instance of `ModuleAndroidKeyboard` then call `start()` on that.

```java
public class ModuleAndroidKeyboard extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT);
    }
}
```

```java
ModuleAndroidKeyboard module = new ModuleAndroidKeyboard();
module.start(); // this line executes the codes of run()
```

To learn more about `Thread` in Java, visit [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_threads.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to sign the apk with a system certificate and register INJECT_EVENTS in the manifest, after which everything worked.